# Why does the PID work, but the title does not?

Tags: vbscript

Long story short, I print shipping labels at my job through a proprietary program that runs through IE. A common shipper is Caterpillar Global Mining, so I made a script to enter that field for me.

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 100
wshShell.AppActivate ("PRINT LABEL")
WScript.Sleep 100
wshShell.SendKeys "caterpillar global mining"
```

I put the cursor in the correct field, hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to run the script, and wham! I don't have to type the company's name 100 times. The problem is, it only works when I enter the PID instead of the title (for example, `1111` instead of `"PRINT LABEL"`). If I use the title in the script, it will bring focus to IE, but lose the cursor position. Using the PID is ok by me, I'm just curious as to why this happens.

UPDATE: after playing around some more I've noticed that there are 2 processes for IE. If I enter the other process PID the script reacts the same way as when I use the title. I am now even more confused. I feel like there is a simple answer, I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

For using the title the string must match the beginning of the window title. Also, you will get the first match, so you need to make the string specific enough. The PID is by design and definition unique, so you don't run into these problems when using a PID in `AppActivate`.

Comment: I would like to use the title, since every time I restart IE i need to enter a new PID. I've gotten to the point where it will bring focus back to IE, but it still loses the cursor position. Is there a way to fix this?